# Getting the information that exists in "Job properties -> Notifications" page?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, msdb

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and I need get some properties from the msdb database.

I need a query to get information that exists in the `Job properties -> Notifications` page.

In which table I can find this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dbo.sysjobs and dbo.sysoperators views provide you the details.  Some simple code (cleaned up from coding errors in first post.):

```
SELECT j.name AS JobName,
   j.notify_level_email, e.name AS EmailOperator,
   j.notify_level_netsend, n.name AS NetSendOperator,  
   j.notify_level_page, p.name AS PagerOperator,
   j.notify_level_eventlog, 
   j.delete_level
FROM dbo.sysjobs j 
  LEFT JOIN dbo.sysoperators e 
     on j.notify_email_operator_id = e.id
  LEFT JOIN dbo.sysoperators n 
     on j.notify_netsend_operator_id = n.id
  LEFT JOIN dbo.sysoperators p 
     on j.notify_page_operator_id = p.id
```

I did not flesh out the notify levels:  0 = none, 1 = succeeds, 2 = fails, 3 = completes.  The delete_level is 0 if the job is not to automatically delete under any circumstance.

Answer (score 4):

Because of where the information is stored in `msdb`, part of the information is obtained when the Job Properties window is initially opened, then more information is queried when you actually click on the Notifications page. SSMS uses an `INSERT`/`EXEC` on the `sp_help_` stored procedures to obtain the operator information, which is pretty unwieldy... so unfortunately, using Profiler in this case to trap the queries isn't particularly helpful.

Here's a completed query that returns all the information from the page in one shot:

```
USE [msdb];
GO

WITH jobStates AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS Level,  'Disabled' AS Description UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,           'On Success' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,           'On Failure' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,           'On Completion'
)
SELECT
    j.job_id,
    j.name,
    es.Description AS EmailOnJobState, e.name AS EmailOperatorName, e.email_address AS EmailOperatorEmailAddress,
    ps.Description AS PageOnJobState, p.name AS PageOperatorName, p.pager_address AS PageOperatorPagerAddress,
    nss.Description AS NetSendOnJobState, ns.name AS NetSendOperatorName, ns.netsend_address AS NetSendOperatorNetSendAddress,
    els.Description AS EventLogOnJobState,
    ds.Description AS DeleteJobOnJobState
    FROM [dbo].[sysjobs] j
    INNER JOIN jobStates es ON es.Level = j.notify_level_email
    INNER JOIN jobStates ps ON ps.Level = j.notify_level_page
    INNER JOIN jobStates nss ON nss.Level = j.notify_level_netsend
    INNER JOIN jobStates els ON els.Level = j.notify_level_eventlog
    INNER JOIN jobStates ds ON ds.Level = j.delete_level
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[sysoperators] e ON (j.notify_level_email > 0) AND (e.id = j.notify_email_operator_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[sysoperators] p ON (j.notify_level_page > 0) AND (p.id = j.notify_page_operator_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[sysoperators] ns ON (j.notify_level_netsend > 0) AND (ns.id = j.notify_netsend_operator_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what you are looking for but, have you tried sp_help_job or sp_helpjobstep?

```
USE msdb;
GO

EXEC dbo.sp_help_jobstep
    @job_name = N'JobName_Here',
    @step_id = 1;
GO
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178599.aspx